# Problems showing the images using elfinder.min.js within elFinder

Tags: elfinder

I've started to look at using the elFinder within my site, doing a test page I have followed what is done within this link and have my page as follows [elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/blob/2.x/elfinder.html)

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>elFinder 2.0</title>

    <!-- jQuery and jQuery UI (REQUIRED) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/ui-themes/smoothness-1.8.23/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css">
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>

    <!-- elFinder CSS (REQUIRED) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/elfinder.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">

    <!-- elFinder JS (REQUIRED) -->
    <script src="js/elfinder.min.js"></script>

    <!-- elFinder initialization (REQUIRED) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Documentation for client options:
        // https://github.com/Studio-42/wiki/Client-configuration-options
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#elfinder').elfinder({
                url : 'php/connector.minimal.php'  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
                // , lang: 'ru'                    // language (OPTIONAL)
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Element where elFinder will be created (REQUIRED) -->
    <div id="elfinder"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have changed the location of where my files are stored within `php/connector.minimal.php` but when I run the page it doesnt return the images that are stored within the `css/images` folder.

Looking at the `console.log` within Chrome it shows this problem
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined`
`TypeError {stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'safari' of undefined"}`

How can I get around this, as all the examples I have found use the same jquery code and all work, but mine doesn't.

Image to show the issue[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have an older version of elfinder with jQuery +1.9. `$.browser` have been removed in jQuery 1.9. There are two ways to handle this: download the newest version [here](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/archive/2.x.zip) or downgrade your jQuery (not recommened).

Comment: I think the issue is with `elfinder.min.js` as the code that you put the link for is the version I already have. When looking at the console in Chrome is errors on line 24 on the above code, but I can't find another version to test

Comment: Thanks I got the files from there, it now has cleared up some issues, I'm still left with an issue around the `jquery.min.js` saying a 404 error on the .tmb folder. I don't quite understand what that is and why it's there. This also stops the icons around the elfinder showing (the icons like download, back, forward etc in the top row)

Comment: `.tbm` is the thumbail folder, which should be automatically created in your files folder. Try to create it by yourself.

Comment: The folder is actually there, it was created by the code, also there are around 35 files within it, I assume they are thumbnails as they are *.png files. the elfinder shows all the folder/files within my Uploads folder, but doesn't show the detail of what they are or the icons at the top of the screen due to the jquery.min.js error/issue

Comment: I've edited the original post to add a picture so it shows the state of where I am at currently

Comment: Okay than you have check a few things:
is the URL right configured in the connector (-> https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options)?
is your server right configured? maybe the blocking you from getting the images. try to put a file into your .tmb folder and then access it over your browser. are you getting an error?
Because of the icons in the toolbar: check the /img folder for the icons. Then check the elfinder.css if they are linked correctly. which version do use from the link above?

Comment: I checked the file when I added it to the .tmb folder and I could see it through the browser, I then tested it within its current folder and it was viewable through the browser also. I changed a few settings within the connector php file from the link you gave an it works :-) My next step is to feed the folder I want from another page and use that so that everyone doesnt see all folders/files just the one they are looking at. elFinder doesnt seem to like being within an existing page I have set up so will look at that. Thanks for your help!